# Unix script to run count query for specific date range

Tags: shell, unix, hive, hiveql

I am getting a GC overhead issue when i am running a count for a date range as it has a huge data to pull, so need a logic to run the query for a specific date range (for example to run query for every 30 days without missing any data ) and sum it up all at the end.

I have tried to run the query for every 30 days, but in this approach ,there might be some chances to miss the data count for few days.

currently , I wrote the below code and am able to run the query successfully,but its very time consuming process, so need a help to change this code for every month or some specific date range instead of running below.

```
while [ ${PART_START_DATE} -le ${RUN_START_DAY} ]
   do
   fb_TEST=$(($fb_TEST+$(hive -S -e "use ${DATABASE};set hive.cli.print.header=false;select count(*) from fb_wrk_tab where date = '${PART_START_DATE}';")))

   PART_START_DATE=`date -d "${PART_START_DATE} 1 days" +%Y%m%d`

   echo "fbwrk_TEST count is"$fb_TEST >> ${LOG_FILE}

   done
```